# Python list of classes , index() not working

Tags: python

Not sure what i'm doing wrong here. I have this class:

```
class Node:
    '''
    Class to contain the lspid seq and all data.
    '''
    def __init__(self, name,pseudonode,fragment,seq_no,data):
        self.name = name
        self.data = {}
        self.pseudonode = pseudonode
        self.seq_no = seq_no
        self.fragment = fragment
    def __unicode__(self):
        full_name = ('%s-%d-%d') %(self.name,self.pseudonode,self.fragment)
        return str(full_name)
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        if self.name > other.name:
            return 1
        elif self.name < other.name:
            return -1
        return 0
    def __repr__(self):
        full_name = ('%s-%d-%d') %(self.name,self.pseudonode,self.fragment)
        #print 'iside Node full_name: {} \n\n\n ------'.format(full_name)
        return str(full_name)
```

and putting some entries in a list :

```
nodes = []
node = Node('0000.0000.0001',0,0,100,{})
nodes.append(node)
>>> nodes
[0000.0000.0001-0-0]
node = Node('0000.0000.0001',1,0,100,{})
nodes.append(node)
>>> nodes
[0000.0000.0001-0-0, 0000.0000.0001-1-0]
```

i'm trying to get the index of a node in list nodes[]

```
>>> node
0000.0000.0001-1-0
>>> nodes.index(node) 
0
```

0 is not what i was expecting. Not sure why this is happening.

edit 
i'm after getting the index of the list where '0000.0000.0001-1-0' is.

Comment: That's how you defined equality.

Comment: "not what i was expecting" — so what _were_ you expecting? And why?

Comment: i was expecting 1 the index of the list where "0000.0000.0001-1-0" is should be 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `index` function, when used on a container, relies on its element's `__cmp__` function to return the index of the first element that it thinks is  equal to the input-object. You probably know as much, since you implemented it for the node. But what you are expecting is that `__cmp__` considers not only the name, but also the pseudonode and the fragment, right?

A straight-forward approach would be to consider them a tuple, which performs a comparison of elements from left to right, until the first inequality was found:

```
def __cmp__(self, other):
    self_tuple = (self.name, self.pseudonode, self.fragment)
    other_tuple = (other.name, other.pseudonode, other.fragment)
    if self_tuple > other_tuple:
        return 1
    elif self_tuple < other_tuple:
        return -1
    return 0
```

If you want another order, you can use the tuples-ordering to define it.

Comment: great. Thanks for the example and for the explanation.